# Get the value of checkbox in wpf

Tags: wpf, checkbox

Below is the `xaml` code I'm using. I'm trying to get the checkbox value in code-behind.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailablePresentationObjects}" >
  <ListBox>
    <CheckBox Content="Puma" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
    <CheckBox Content="NIke" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Adidas" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
    <CheckBox Content="reebok" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
  </ListBox>
</ListBox>
<Button x:Name="btnLaunchCache" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
        IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsButtonEnabled,Mode=TwoWay}" 
        Click="BtnLaunchCache_Click">
<TextBlock>Submit</TextBlock>
```

Comment: **Edit**: Now that we can see the whole markup: Why would you put a listbox inside of a listbox filled with checkboxes and add a binding to an itemssource and bind all checkboxes to the same source. Could it be that you have **no** idea what you are doing?

Comment: for ex . i need to get if user has selected puma checkbox , may be what i am doing is wrong , i am a newbie . Please suggest me how to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an "x:Name" property to your checkboxes:

```
   <CheckBox x:Name="chkPuma" Content="Puma" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
```

Then you can access "chkPuma.IsChecked" in the code behind.

Comment: That would of course work, but would defeat the purpose of the existing viewmodel. The manually added checkbox should probably not even exist.

Comment: Thanks @Robin , thats what i needed .

Comment: @eth_92 Of course Manfred is right, it is kind of against the whole idea. I propose you find yourself an introduction to MVVM on the web, to have the logic nicely decoupled from the view.